# Excel 2016 - Add data from adjacent cell in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

A1 contains `1Q18`, B1 contains `='J:\USA\DataHub\[DATA.xlsm]2018'!$G$6`

I need the "2018" in B1 to come from A1.
I can get it from A1 with `="20"&RIGHT($A$1,2)` --> 2018

How do I put that formula for 2018 into the B1 formula?

I have tried: `='J:\USA\DataHub\[DATA.xlsm]'INDIRECT("20"&RIGHT($A$1,2))!$G$6` and
              `='J:\USA\DataHub\[DATA.xlsm]'&INDIRECT("20"&RIGHT($A$1,2))!$G$6`
without success.

Comment: you can use INDIRECT

Comment: Thanks for the reply PeterH.  I edited my question to show that I had already attempted to use INDIRECT, obviously incorrectly. I don't quite understand the proper way to make that INDIRECT function fit it the formula.

Comment: try using an & after the closing bracket for the INDIRECT

Comment: If I'm understanding you Peter, that is what I did in my second example.  Should the single quote be where I placed it, immediately after the "]"?

Comment: I mean ='J:\USA\DataHub[DATA.xlsm]'&INDIRECT("20"&RIGHT($A$1,2))&"!"&$G$6

Comment: I do actually have a backslash before the "[", but it doesn't show up here. I suspect that's due to the way the forum uses brackets.

Comment: FYI - To show a backslash here in comments, you need to tag it as code with the `\`` character on both sides of the code:  `='J:\USA\DataHub\[DATA.xlsm]'&INDIRECT("20"&RIGHT($A$1,2))&"!"&$G$6`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, did my Answer help?

Answer (score 1):

This formula should work:

```
=INDIRECT("'J:\USA\DataHub[DATA.xlsm]"&"20"&RIGHT($A$1,2)&"'!$G$6")
```

A caveat with `INDIRECT()` is that the book you're referencing must be open.  Otherwise you get `#REF` errors.